# Error al realizar un gráfico de dispersión para dos grupos diferentes

Tags: r

Estudio intentando realizar un gráfico de dispersión para dos grupos juntos en el mismo gráfico.

Para esto partí de un dataframe como este, la cual importada de una tabla de spss (9092 filas x1133 variables)

```
     BD<- read_sav("BD.sav")


      BD:   SEX      IMC     EFISEMA
             1      28.08    0.06381
             2      38.08    0.55221
             1      21.08    0.15244
             1      28.08    0.55214
             2      18.08    0.06321
             1      38.08    0.06781
             1      21.08    0.01581
             1      25.08    0.06771
             2      26.08    0.06371
             1      19.08    0.06781
```

Para ello he realizado dos gráficos de dispersión, uno para cada sexo:

```
        Cor_mujeres<-subset(BD,SEX==2);dim(Cor_mujeres)
        Cor_hombres<-subset(BD,SEX==1);dim(Cor_hombres)

        sp <- ggscatter(Cor_hombres, x = "TOTALEMPHYSEMAVOLUME_FIXEDT_0001", y = "IMC2",
                        add = "reg.line", 
                        main="Men", 
                        xlab="%total emphysema volume ", ylab="IMC" ,# Add regressin line
                        add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "lightgray"), # Customize reg. line
                        conf.int = TRUE # Add confidence interval
        )
        sp + stat_cor(p.accuracy = 0.001, r.accuracy = 0.01,label.x = 30, label.y = 150)


        sp <- ggscatter(Cor_mujeres, x = "TOTALEMPHYSEMAVOLUME_FIXEDT_0001", y = "IMC2",
                        add = "reg.line", 
                        main="Men", 
                        xlab="%total emphysema volume ", ylab="IMC" ,# Add regressin line
                        add.params = list(color = "blue", fill = "lightgray"), # Customize reg. line
                        conf.int = TRUE # Add confidence interval
        )
        sp + stat_cor(p.accuracy = 0.001, r.accuracy = 0.01,label.x = 30, label.y = 150)
```

Y funciona corretamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema viene cuando quiero realizar un único plot para ambos sexos:

```
        ggscatter(BD, x = "TOTALEMPHYSEMAVOLUME_FIXEDT_0001", y =     "POFEV1_PERCENT_PREDICTED",
                  add = "reg.line",                         
                  conf.int = TRUE,                          
                  color = "SEX", palette = "jco",           
                  shape = "SEX"                      
        )+
          stat_cor(aes(color = SEX), label.x = 3)
```

que me aparece el siguiente error:

```
        Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type haven_labelled/vctrs_vctr/double. Defaulting to continuous.
        Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape
        Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

¿Dónde está mi problema? Gracias de antemano

Comment: Prueba convertir `SEX` en un `factor`:  `BD$SEX <- factor(BD$SEX)`

Comment: Efectivamente @PatricioMoracho tras realizar tu sugerencia han salido ambas gráficas. Muchas gracias. Pon tu sugerencia como comentario y te lo puntuo como solución. Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo fundamental del error es:

> Error: A continuous variable can not be mapped to shape

Si vemos `shape` apunta a `SEX` y si bien los datos parecen ser 1 o 2, probablemente se trate de una variable numérica, por consiguiente una variable continua, y claro, no se puede "mapear" `shape` que es un conjunto finito de símbolos a un variable cuyo valor virtualmente es infinito.

Claramente el sexo es una variable discreta, por lo que la solución es transformar la columna en un `factor` (podría ser también una cadena):

```
BD$SEX <- factor(BD$SEX, levels = c(1,2), labels = c("Hombre", "Mujer"))
```